# DNS servers with Amazon Web Services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just migrated to Amazon Web Services with Lightsail and created a new instance of Plesk Hosting Stack on Ubuntu. I already have my hosting with Plesk and I have created my first Website, I have already uploaded the files and created the database, but it turns out that I have my domain with another provider (https://mi.com.co/) and I need to modify the DNS records of my domain to point to my hosting that I created with AWS.

How I do this? What are the names of the DNS records that I should put in my domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to change the NS at your host provider.

take a look in this documentation: [lightsail host guide](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry#lightail-change-the-name-servers)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious way is to go with the solution @Matebas posted. Of course you can also change the Domain Provider for your domain and move it to AWS [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/de/route53/). For this you need to make a "domain transfer" to AWS.

This way you have all in one place but you might have additional costs depending when you last renewed your domain at the old domain provider.